# Multiple Places Show on Google Place ID Finder - Remove Duplicates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-my-business-api

The Google Place ID Finder shows 3 separate locations for "Creation Museum" in Kentucky, USA.

Place ID Finder:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

- Correct: Creation Museum, Bullittsburg Church Road, Petersburg, KY, USA
- WRONG: Creation museum, Merchants Street, Florence, KY, USA
- WRONG: Creation museum, creation museum, Cincinnati, KY, USA

Google My Business support refuses to support this issue since they can find no associated GMB pages to these incorrect locations. How do you remove the incorrect/wrong locations from Google Places?

Comment: What are you using the PlaceId for?  Why does it matter that there are two entries that are not the business you want?

Answer (score 0):

Those "incorrect" locations appear on Google Maps also:

- [5905 Merchants St, Florence, KY 41042](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Creation+museum/@39.00908,-84.6547603,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8841c79891e65e61:0x240bacf079dcff9a!8m2!3d39.0090759!4d-84.6525716)
- [creation museum, Cincinnati, KY 45206](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Creation+museum/@39.1180351,-84.5007688,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8841b383ad25cb2f:0xb7b45e4bd20ea5e9!8m2!3d39.118031!4d-84.4985801)

To fix data problems on Google Maps, click on the "Send Feedback" link in the lower right hand bottom corner of the map, and let them know it is "Wrong Information" (if you know that there is no such thing at that location)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip! I submitted feedback to Google Maps on those issues. Appreciate the help!